# is it possible to use COLT with large matrices?

Tags: java, numerical, colt

I started using COLT at some point, and now my code is using a lot of its functionality.

I now need to be able to handle large *sparse* tensors or matrices. The tensors are very sparse, but their dimensions can be quite large.

It seems like I can't use COLT for this end, because it requires the total number of potential elements in a tensor/matrix be less than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Is that so? There is nothing I can do even for sparse matrices? I find it rather surprising - I thought COLT is a state-of-the-art implementation of the BLAS routines, and sparse matrices naturally could exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE in their total capacity.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, I had a sparse matrix singular value decomposition problem in Java, and did a performance test comparing COLT to passing the matrix through a file to Matlab. Matlab won, largely because it had better support for sparse matrix operations.

I ended up with a mixed language application that did all the data collection, organization, storage, and reporting in Java, but used Matlab for the core linear algebra operations.